# How to move subviews lifecycle responsibilities to Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

**Question** *How to move subviews lifecycle responsibilities from `MyView` to `Marionette`? (see code below)*

The problem here is that `items` array is formed dynamically on the server, and I don't want to iterate through them in `MyView`. Do I need `Marionette.CollectionView`?

**Code:**

I have `my-view.hbs` template:

```
{{#each items}}
  <button class="button">name</button>
  <div name="target"/>  <!-- each target div should contain a subview -->
{{/each}}
```

And view which renders it:

```
var MyView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: Templates['my-view.hbs'],

  render: function() {
    var items = [ //actually they come from server
      {name: 'car'},
      {name: 'bike'},
      {name: 'skiboard'},
    ];
    this.$el.html(
      this.template({ items: items })
    );
    this.renderSubViews();
    return this;
  },
  /**
   * It creates, renders and append subViews manually.
   * TODO: move responsibilities to Marionette
   */
  renderSubViews: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.subViews = [];
    self.$('div[name=target]').each(function(index, subViewContainer) {
      var subView = new SubView();
      self.subViews.add(subView);
      subView.render();
      $(subViewContainer).append(subView.$el);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If short, yes, you need **Composite** or **Collection** View.
Also i recommend you to use Collection instead plain object, it will help you to make easier communication between data (model) and you views:

```
var ItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'unnamed'
        }
    }), 
    ItemsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ItemModel
    }),

    MyChildView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: Templates['my-view.hbs']
    }),
    MyView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView: MyChildView,
        collection: new ItemsCollection([
            {name: 'car'},
            {name: 'bike'},
            {name: 'skiboard'}
        ])
    });
```

also your template will be easier:

```
<button class="button">name</button>
<div name="target"/>
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer! Also how to pass additional options from parent view to child view constructor?

Comment: using `childViewOptions` - http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childviewoptions.